# How to solve 'Error: Agent admitted failure to sign' when trying to establish SSH connection to Github

Tags: github, ssh, ssh-keys

I'm following the Odin Project in Ubuntu and after adding an SSH key, I typed this to test connection:

$ ssh -T git@github.com

The output was the predictable:

> The authenticity of host 'github.com (IP ADDRESS)' can't be established.
> ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:+DiY3wvvV6TuJJhbpZisF/zLDA0zPMSvHdkr4UvCOqU.
> Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?

The fingerprint matches one of Github's public fingerprints, so I typed

$ yes

Then I got the message:

> Agent admitted failure to sign using the key.
> debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
> Permission denied (publickey).

So I went to their page titled "Error: Agent admitted failure to sign" and typed:

$ eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"

To get the Agent pid, then on their example it's

> ssh-add

Which on the page outputs something, but for me, nothing. If I type their next example,

$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/my_other_key

I get an error message, unlike the example.